# Pass .txt list of .jpgs to convert (bash)

Tags: bash, shell

I'm currently working on an exercise that requires me to write a shell script whose function is to take a single command-line argument that is a directory. The script takes the given directory, and finds all the .jpgs in that directory and its sub-directories, and creates an image-strip of all the .jpgs in order of modification time (newest on bottom).

So far, I've written:

```
#!bin/bash/

dir=$1 #the first argument given will be saved as the dir variable


#find all .jpgs in the given directory
#then ls is run for the .jpgs, with the date format %s (in seconds)
#sed lets the 'cut' process ignore the spaces in the columns
#fields 6 and 7 (the name and the time stamp) are then cut and sorted by modification date
#then, field 2 (the file name) is selected from that input
#Finally, the entire sorted output is saved in a .txt file

find "$dir" -name "*.jpg" -exec ls -l --time-style=+%s {} + | sed 's/  */ /g' | cut -d' ' -f6,7 | sort -n | cut -d' ' -f2 > jgps.txt
```

The script correctly outputs the directory's .jpgs in order of time modification. The part that I am currently struggling on is how to give the list in the .txt file to the `convert -append` command that will create an image-strip for me (For those who aren't aware of that command, what would be inputted is: `convert -append image1.jpg image2.jpg image3.jpg IMAGESTRIP.jpg`with IMAGESTRIP.jpg being the name of the completed image strip file made up of the previous 3 images).

I can't quite figure out how to pass the .txt list of files and their paths to this command. I've been scouring the man pages to find a possible solution but no viable ones have arisen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the list of filenames in a file called `filelist.txt` and call `convert` with the filename prepended by an ampersand:

```
convert @filelist.txt -append result.jpg
```

Here's a little example:

```
# Create three blocks of colour
convert xc:red[200x100]    red.png
convert xc:lime[200x100]   green.png
convert xc:blue[200x100]   blue.png

# Put their names in a file called "filelist.txt"
echo "red.png green.png blue.png" > filelist.txt

# Tell ImageMagick to make a strip
convert @filelist.txt +append strip.png
```

[image]

As there's always some image with a pesky space in its name...

```
# Make the pesky one
convert -background black -pointsize 128 -fill white label:"Pesky" -resize x100 "image with pesky space.png"

# Whack it in the list for IM
echo "red.png green.png blue.png 'image with pesky space.png'" > filelist.txt

# IM do your stuff
convert @filelist.txt +append strip.png
```

[image]

By the way, it is generally poor practice to parse the output of `ls` in case there are spaces in your filenames. If you want to find a list of images, across directories and sort them by time, look at something like this:

```
# Find image files only - ignoring case, so "JPG", "jpg" both work
find . -type f -iname \*.jpg

# Now exec `stat` to get the file ages and quoted names
... -exec stat --format "%Y:%N {} \;

# Now sort that, and strip the times and colon at the start
... | sort -n | sed 's/^.*://'

# Put it all together
find . -type f -iname \*.jpg -exec stat --format "%Y:%N {} \; | sort -n | sed 's/^.*://'
```

Now you can either redirect all that to `filelist.txt` and call `convert` like this:

```
find ...as above... > file list.txt
convert @filelist +append strip.jpg
```

Or, if you want to avoid intermediate files and do it all in one go, you can make this monster where `convert` reads the filelist from its standard input stream:

```
find ...as above... | sed 's/^.*://' | convert @- +append strip.jpg
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you! Question: Why do I need the '@' sign in order to make it take the .txt file as an argument?

Comment: That's just the syntax, else it would assume the file was an image rather than a list of image filenames.

Comment: Well, I spoke too soon. I ran the script once and it produced what I expected. I ran it one more time to squeeze out some extra dopamine for a job finally done, but it now consistently produces 1 image strip of THREE of the image strip (so image 1-8 attached to image 1-8 attached to image 1-8 again, all as the result.jpg). Why is it suddenly looping it? A further question: how would I go about getting the "result.jpg" name of the .jpg to be whatever the command line argument is,but with '_'s instead of '/'s in the name (Ex: Exercise3/Test1/ produces Exercise3_Test1.jpg)

Comment: I am not at my computer right now to test... maybe try with spaces between filenames rather than newlines between them.

Comment: Same result. There's no rush though. I appreciate your knowledge anyway!

Comment: I've been fiddling around with it and now it produces a single imagestrip of FIVE imagestrips! It seems to be compounding somewhere but I can't find where...

Comment: By the way, it is generally a bad idea to parse the output of `ls` in case your filenames contain spaces or newlines.... maybe try `-exec stat ... {}` instead -depending on your OS.

Comment: I've had issues with spaces before. That's why the sed is in there. What confuses me is that it worked upon first running the script, and then all of the sudden exponentially produces image strips upon running it more. I've tried putting in -exec and now it doesn't run at all. I'll try to run it on another machine and see if the script's problem is that multiple runs on the same machine will cause this. Also, how would I get the input from the command line to be the name of the imagestrip.jpg? I've tried $1 but it isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

`xargs` is your friend:

```
find "$dir" -name "*.jpg" -exec ls -l --time-style=+%s {} + | sed 's/  */ /g' | cut -d' ' -f6,7 | sort -n | cut -d' ' -f2 | xargs -I files convert -append files IMAGESTRIP.jpg
```

### Explanation

The basic use of xargs is:

```
find . -type f | xargs rm
```

That is, you specify a command to xargs, it appends the arguments it receives from standard input and then executes it. The avobe line would execute:

```
rm file1 file2 ...
```

But you also need to specify a final argument to the command, so you need to use the xarg `-I` parameter, which tells xargs the string you will use after to indicate where the arguments read from standard input will be put.

So, we use the string `files` to indicate it. Then we write the command, putting the string `files` where the variable arguments will be, resulting in:

```
xargs -I files convert -append files IMAGESTRIP.jpg
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip! I've looked into the man pages and that looks like that's what I want to do. A file named IMAGESTRIP.jpg is now created, however it only displays 1 image, not the 8 that I need to append. I guess I can try a while loop or something of the sort to append all the images together... but that line is getting pretty long. Is there a way to split this long line into several smaller lines to ease reading?

Comment: I have improved the answer with some explanation. About your comment, it should display all, maybe not all files are being added by xargs, you can confirm it by substituting convert by `echo`, to see what is being executed.

Comment: About splitting the line, you can put \ and continue in the next line.

Comment: All the .jpgs I want to make a strip out of are being listed, but only the last/newest one is being produced by the script when I use the convert command.

Comment: It may be a convert issue, check the `convert` manual to see if you are using it properly.

Comment: I've looked through the man pages and I've looked over the exercise sheet. The way I'm using convert is correct. I think it's an issue with xargs passing only 1 line instead of all 8 that the command outputs...\